# Typing Nested Object with Flow

Tags: visual-studio-code, flowtype

I have 3 types in different files. One includes the other two as a definition for one of its properties.

```
// /flow-typed/type1.js

declare type1 = {
  prop1: string,
  prop2: string,
}
```

and

```
// /flow-typed/type2.js

declare type2 = {
  prop1: number,
  prop2: number,
}
```

then `type3` uses the other two
    // /flow-typed/type3.js

```
declare type3 = {
  prop1: type1,
  prop2: type2,
}
```

In `type3.js`, Flow is giving me a `property ... not found in object literal` error for every property of `type1` and `type2`.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused about `declare`, I only use it for library definitions. Try using `export type` instead in the first two files, combined with `import {type} from './type1.js';` and the same for `type2`, imported in _type3.js_.

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve is import/export throughout my codebase. Declare does that everywhere but in this specific case.

Comment: If it doesn't work but `type` does than that's the solution. Maybe you have to bite the bullet and explicitly import everywhere, which is what I do. I'm not saying it's convenient and/or justified, but there are sooooo many issues with those 3rd party type systems I've given up yelling each time I find a bug and just quietly work around it best I can. Issues are fixed **very** slowly for Flow (issue list for TypeScript is just as long though).

Comment: New reply because new thought: Is it possible that the problem is the (unknown) sequence in which Flow parses the files? With explicit imports you determine that sequence, but here Flow might go through file3 before it looked at the others. I don't know how the parsing is done, if it's just a single pass, but maybe the issue is at least in that direction. Maybe you can put those declarations in a library definitions file, maybe then they are found earlier?

Comment: That's an interesting thought. Thanks.